# How do I insert a transition delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a simple JavaScript to close and open a menu but I was wondering how to insert a delay when opening the menu.

**HTML**

```
 <a href="#1" onclick="return show();">open Menu</a>
 <a href="#1" onclick="return hide();">Hide Menu</a>

   <div id="container">
     <div id="side-menu" style="display:none">Left menu</div>
     <div id="body">body</div>
   </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 #container{ position: absolute;display: table}
 #side-menu, #body {display:table-cell;}
 #body {width: 80%;}
 #side-menu {width: 260px;}
```

The JavaScript:

```
 <script> 
    function show() { 
     if(document.getElementById('side-menu').style.display=='none') { 
        document.getElementById('side-menu').style.display='block';            

     } 
      return false;
     } 
      function hide() { 
        if(document.getElementById('side-menu').style.display=='block') { 
        document.getElementById('side-menu').style.display='none'; 
     } 
        return false;
     }   
</script>
```

When you click the open menu, it opens the side bar menu and pushes the body to the right.
My question is how to make it pushes the body to the right with a delay or say a transition maybe about .8s.

Is there any way JavaScript can handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using jquery

```
$("#side-menu").hide(800)
```

You can also add different types of [animations](https://jqueryui.com/hide/)

Updated your javascript code:

```
function showHide() { 
  if($("#side-menu").is(":visible") { 
      $("#side-menu").hide(800);         
  } else {
      $("#side-menu").show(800);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. I followed the link you showed, great for learning. Just new with java script and query, still have to figure out how to use both of them in this case. How do I insert the line of code you sent  $("#side-menu").hide(800)   in my own codes above. Sorry for being very blank

Comment: I updated my answer. You should try and learn jquery, it's a lot easier than vanilla javascript I find

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer a fully CSS solution:

```
#side-menu {
    left: -260px;
    width: 260px;
    position: absolute;
    transition-property: left;
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
}
#side-menu.open {
    left: 0;
}
```

(Note that I'm being lazy here and absolutely positioning the element, which will slide it out over the body.  That's because it's easiest to demonstrate a transition using `left`; you could use `width` instead for a positioned element.)

Answer (score 0):

This is without jQuery and without sliding:
Your buttons:

```
 <a href="#1" onclick="show();">open Menu</a>
 <a href="#1" onclick="hide();">Hide Menu</a>
```

Your routines:

```
function show() {
  setTimeout( function() {document.getElementById('side-menu').style.display='block'; }, 800);            
} 
function hide() { 
  setTimeout( function() {document.getElementById('side-menu').style.display='none'; }, 800);
}
```